# Fire jquery effect once for each mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I stop a jquery effect after it's first execution on a mouseover? I want the box to bounce once and stop even if the mouse remains inside the box and repeat this for every time the mouse goes back into the box. Currently it runs the effect infinitely when mouse is inside the box. Thanks in advance.

I have made an example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rxhzg/)

I tried:
`one("mouseover", function() { $( "#div1" ).effect("bounce", "slow"); });`

However this will not fire the event again when you leave the box and come back into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$( "#div1, #div2" ).one('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).effect("bounce", { times: 1 }, "slow");
});

$( "#div1, #div2" ).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).one('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).effect("bounce", { times: 1 }, "slow");
});
});
```

check this http://jsfiddle.net/Rxhzg/6/

OR check this one http://jsfiddle.net/Rxhzg/8/ because the above one will continue bounce if mouse is at bottom of box.

```
$( ".parentDiv" ).one('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).find('.navBox').effect("bounce", { times: 1 }, "slow");
});

$( ".parentDiv" ).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).one('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).find('.navBox').effect("bounce", { times: 1 }, "slow");
});
});
```

Comment: Dude this is awesome! The exact functionality I was looking for! Can you please explain what is going on in order for it to work? Thanks

Comment: one is to execute one time, so attach again on mouseleave so that it will execute again one time on next mouseover.

Answer (score 5):

`.one()` works:

```
$( "#div1, #div2" ).one('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).effect("bounce", "slow");
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Rxhzg/1/

*UPDATE (based on updated question)*

If by "on mouseover once" you mean just "one bounce" - add `times` parameter:

```
$( "#div1, #div2" ).mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).effect("bounce", { times: 1 }, "slow");
});
```

**DEMO 2** http://jsfiddle.net/Rxhzg/4/

Comment: I didn't knew any such function in Jquery..
It works very well :)

Comment: oops sorry I should have been clearer. `.one()` does work, however it will not let the effect fire again when  you leave the box and come back into it.

Comment: @Jaiesh_bhai Um.. And what do you mean by "onmouseover once?"

Comment: So i guess what I am trying to say is: Each time the mouse enters the box, the box should do the bounce effect once (and not in a continuous loop until the mouse leaves the box)

Comment: @Jaiesh_bhai this is what it does in the demo - it does it once. *Not* continuously

Comment: @YuriyGalanter Each time the mouse enters the box

Comment: @Jaiesh_bhai Yup see it now. I was testing in Chrome where it doesn't happen, now i see it in IE and FF

Answer (score 0):

This example is similar to other answers, however it abstracts the original bind into a function for reusability.

```
var $target = $( "#div1, #div2" );

function bounce() {
  $target.one('mouseover', function () {
    $(this).effect("bounce", { times: 1 }, "slow");
  });
}

$target.on('mouseout', bounce);      

bounce();
```